# KSQL table not able to see the data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Confluent Platform: 6.1.1

Issue: Unable to see the data on ksql table :-

1.) First created topic :-

```
./kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic COUNTRY-CSV
Created topic COUNTRY-CSV.
```

2.) Sent some data to this topic :-

```
./kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic COUNTRY-CSV --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=:
>AU:AU,Australia     
>IN:IN,India
```

3.) Created KSQL table :-

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE COUNTRY_TABLE (countrycode VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, countryname VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'COUNTRY-CSV', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');
 Message    
---------------
 Table created 
---------------
ksql>
```

4.) Already set the below property :-

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.xreset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'earliest' to 'earliest'.
ksql>
```

5.) Not able to see the data onto the kSQL table :-

```
ksql> select countrycode, countryname from COUNTRY_TABLE EMIT CHANGES;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|COUNTRYCODE                                |COUNTRYNAME                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
^CQuery terminated
ksql>
```

6.) Verified that data is coming well into the kafka topic, along with the KEY :-

```
ksql> print 'COUNTRY-CSV';
Key format: KAFKA_STRING
Value format: KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/05/09 09:34:23.799 Z, key: AU, value: AU,Australia
rowtime: 2021/05/09 09:34:29.185 Z, key: IN, value: IN,India
rowtime: 2021/05/09 09:34:39.701 Z, key: US, value: US,Unites-States
```

Unable to see the data (posted manually by Kafka console producer) onto the ksql table ? Any help/pointers shall be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the answer by going to the logs using  `confluent local current` :-

I was producing 2 columns in value separated by the comma, whereas in ksql-table, it was expecting only one column.

Worked with this data :-

```
./kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic COUNTRY-CSV --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=:
>JP:JAPAN    
>AU:AUSTRALIA    
>IN:INDIA
>BEL:BELGIUM
>SA:SOUTH-AFRICA
>GB:GREAT-BRITAIN
```

Obtained following output :-

```
ksql> select * from COUNTRY_CSV EMIT CHANGES;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|COUNTRYCODE                                                                |COUNTRYNAME                                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|JP                                                                         |JAPAN                                                                      |
|AU                                                                         |AUSTRALIA                                                                  |
|IN                                                                         |INDIA                                                                      |
|BEL                                                                        |BELGIUM                                                                    |
|SA                                                                         |SOUTH-AFRICA                                                               |
^CQuery terminated
ksql>
```

Thanks to all.